# Graphical Glitching after teleporting FPS Controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After teleporting the RigidBodyFPSController, there is strange graphical glitching that I have no idea how to fix. Here is a video showing the glitching: https://youtu.be/iAD86OKVhlU

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I figured it out. For anyone who has the same issue, it seemed to be something weird with the skybox or something. I just encased the level in a dark room and it fixed the glitching. Sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the RigidBodyFPSController, it is bad camera clear flag setting. Try using solid color as your main camera clear setting.
Here is [documentation reference.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CameraClearFlags.html)